# Django Templates accessing JS script

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

My template `zone1map.html`has the dependency of `matrix.js` I am getting `Error:[02/Feb/2016 13:09:07] "GET /v3app/zone1 HTTP/1.1" 200 10513
Not Found: /v3app/matrix.js` . However matrix.js is located in V3/v3app, templates folder is in V3,
My view code is:

```
def zone1(request):
    temp=controller.workDB()
    array=[]
    while temp:
        string = temp.pop()
        string1 = string.to_JSON()
        array.append(string1)
     fileDes=""
     return render_to_response('zone1map.html', {"JSON": json.dumps(array), "fileDes":fileDes})
```

call inside zone1map.html
`<script src="matrix.js"></script>`

Comment: See [Managing static files (e.g. images, JavaScript, CSS)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/) and may be [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should serve the `js` as a static file from a separate folder. Django manages these files in a special way. This is [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/). An advantage of doing it this way, is it allows a 'dumb' webserver to serve these files on deployment.